# (TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple) In Planetary Orbits Simulator

Tags: python, arrays, function, numpy, vpython

I have been trying to organise this program into loads of functions to make it more modular, but I have run into this error

```
 Traceback (most recent call last):
   File "N:\Starry\Planetary Orbits Ver 6.py", line 100
     Forces(pos, Radii, Masses)# Computes all the forces between masses
   File "N:\Starry\Planetary Orbits Ver 6.py", line 74, in Forces
     r = pos-pos[:,newaxis] # all pairs of star-to-star vectors (Where r is the Relative Position Vector
 TypeError: tuple indices must be integers, not tuple
```

I'm not sure I have set up the functions correctly, which is why im getting the error in the function.

Or is it because i've used a numpy function inside the Forces function?

```
from visual import *
from time import clock
from random import random

# Stars interacting gravitationally
# Program uses numpy arrays for high speed computations


Nstars = int(input("Number of stars: "))  # change this to have more or fewer stars

G = 6.7e-11 # Universal gravitational constant

# Typical values
Msun = 2E30
Rsun = 2E9
vsun = 0.8*sqrt(G*Msun/Rsun)
dt = 10.0   #Reprensents the change in time
Nsteps = 0
time = clock()
Nhits = 0

Stars = []
colors = [color.red, color.green, color.blue,
          color.yellow, color.cyan, color.magenta]
PositionList = []
MomentumList = []
MassList = []
RadiusList = []
pos = ()
Radii = ()
Masses = ()


def Calculations(SpeedX, SpeedY, SpeedZ, x, y, z, Mass, Radius):
    px = Mass*(SpeedX)
    py = Mass*(SpeedY)
    pz = Mass*(SpeedZ)
    PositionList.append((x,y,z))
    MomentumList.append((px,py,pz))
    MassList.append(Mass)
    RadiusList.append(Radius)

def StarCreation(Stars,x,y,z,Radius):
    Stars = Stars+[sphere(pos=(x,y,z), radius=Radius, color=colors[i % 6],
                   make_trail=True, interval=10)]


def DataCollection():
    x = input("Please enter The x position of the Star: ")
    y = input("Please enter The y position of the Star: ")
    z = input("Please enter The z position of the Star: ")
    Radius = input("Please enter the Radius of the Star: ")
    StarCreation(Stars,x,y,z,Radius)
    Mass = input("Please enter the Mass of the Star: ")
    SpeedX = input("Please enter the X speed of Star: ")
    SpeedY = input("Please enter the Y speed of Star: ")
    SpeedZ = input("Please enter the Z speed of Star: ")
    Calculations(SpeedX, SpeedY, SpeedZ, x, y, z, Mass, Radius)

def Momenta(Momentum, Masses):
    vcm = sum(Momentum)/sum(Masses) # velocity of center of mass
    Momentum = Momentum-Masses*vcm # make total initial momentum equal zero

def ListToArray(PositionList, MomentumList, MassList, RadiusList):
    pos = array(PositionList)
    Momentum = array(MomentumList)
    Masses = array(MassList)
    Masses.shape = (Nstars,1) # Numeric Python: (1 by Nstars) vs. (Nstars by 1)
    Radii = array(RadiusList)
    Momenta(Momentum, Masses)

def Forces(pos, Radii, Masses):
    # Compute all forces on all stars
    r = pos-pos[:,newaxis] # all pairs of star-to-star vectors (Where r is the Relative Position Vector
    for n in range(Nstars):
        r[n,n] = 1e6  # otherwise the self-forces are infinite
    rmag = sqrt(sum(square(r),-1)) # star-to-star scalar distances
    hit = less_equal(rmag,Radii+Radii[:,newaxis])-identity(Nstars)
    hitlist = sort(nonzero(hit.flat)[0]).tolist() # 1,2 encoded as 1*Nstars+2
    F = G*Masses*Masses[:,newaxis]*r/rmag[:,:,newaxis]**3 # all force pairs

def UpdateMomentaPositions(Momentum, pos, Masses):
    Momentum = Momentum+sum(F,1)*dt         
    pos = pos+(Momentum/Masses)*dt

def UpdateDisplay(pos):
    Stars[i].pos = pos[i]


#~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ Actual Proagram ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~#

for i in range(Nstars):
    DataCollection()

ListToArray(PositionList, MomentumList, MassList, RadiusList)

while True:

    rate(100) # No more than 100 loops per second on fast computers
    Forces(pos, Radii, Masses)# Computes all the forces between masses

    for n in range(NStars):
        F[n,n] = 0 # No self forces

    UpdateMomentaPositions(Momentum,pos,Mass) # Updates the Momentum and Positions of Stars

    for i in range(Nstars):
        UpdateDisplay(pos) # Updates the 3D displays position of Masses
```

Comment: I have never seen this subscripting: r = pos-pos[:,newaxis]. Why do you have a comma in there?

Comment: also... if pos is a tuple... I don't think you can subtract tuples.

Comment: You use numpy array syntax for pos, yet you define it as a tuple. Also there seem to be missing import (newaxis comes from np) in your MCVE.